# Is it impossible to check for empty dates OnClick?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check if a date value is empty, and if it is, show a popup saying that it is.

With a bit of searching around i came with a problem identical to mine, where the value would never be empty, as it was fixed to a default "mm/dd/yyyy" value.

The answer to that question came with a JsFiddle that worked flawlessly, however, when i tried to insert it into my code, i couldn't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"> <input type="Date" name='ExpStartDate' style="font-size: 8pt; width: 130px; height: 30px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; display:none" id=ExpStartDate style='display:none;'></td>
                        </br>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td>
                                <input class="botao" name="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update"  onclick="CheckEmpty()" style="width: 120px;">
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                        <SCRIPT language=JavaScript type="text/javascript">
                      function CheckEmpty(){
                      var date = document.getElementById("ExpStartDate").value;
                       if (!date) {
                       alert("No value!")
                      }
                 }
        </script>
```

My first assumption was a problem with the OnClick function, as maybe for some reason it would be impossible to call this function and have it work. So, what do i replace it with?

Comment: Your HTML seems pretty invalid

Comment: Oh, yeah, i cut off some parts accidentally to focus on the javascript, let me fix it

Comment: You're just checking if the "date" variable has a value. An empty date could be 01-01-1900, or something simular, depending on where you are getting that date from.

Comment: you can simply use type="date" and required="required"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your element id in `getElementById`.

```js
function CheckEmpty() {
  var date = document.getElementById("ExpStartDate").value;
  console.log(date);
  if (!date) {
    alert("No value!")
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name='ExpStartDate' style="font-size: 8pt; width: 130px; height: 30px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px" id="ExpStartDate">

<input class="botao" name="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update" onclick="CheckEmpty()" style="width: 120px;">
```

Comment: I don't understand, the answer is perfect, but does not work in my code, for some reason. I tried straight up copying it over to my code, and nothing...

Great answer though, thanks anyway

Comment: What is the output that you are getting?

Comment: Write this method in `<head>`

Comment: Yes it is, your answer did it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with your spelling ie

```
document.getElementById("ExpStartDateDate").value;
```

will be like this

```
 <SCRIPT language=JavaScript type="text/javascript">
                  function CheckEmpty(){
                  var date = document.getElementById("ExpStartDate").value;
                   if (!date) {
                   alert("No value!")
                  }
             }
    </script>
```

Hope this will helps.